# Number of solutions in differential equation with polynomial terms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

I am working on a complicated equation with a third-degree polynomial and a first-order differential term. 
In detail the equation is of the form:

$$a x^3 + bx^2 + (c+dx')x+ ex'=0 $$
where letters $a,b,c,d,e$ are real numbers, $x$ is the unknown variable and $x'$ is the derivative of $x$.

Does this equation belong to a well-know class of functions? If it is not possible to find a solution, I would be at least interested in knowing how many solutions are available or how to tackle this problem.

Does it exist for this kind of mixtures between polynomials and differential equations a general rule?

Thanks for attention.

Comment: is here $$x'=x'(t)$$?

Comment: It is not time, it is the derivative with respect to a parameter that can assume continuously values in real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you solve for $\dot{x}$ you will see that it is a separable ODE

$$\dot{x}=\dfrac{ax^3+bx^2+cx}{e-dx}$$

$$\implies \dfrac{e-dx}{ax^3+bx^2+cx}\mathrm{dx}=\mathrm{dt}$$
$$\implies \int\dfrac{e-dx}{ax^3+bx^2+cx}\mathrm{dx}=t+c$$
$$\implies \int\dfrac{e}{ax^3+bx^2+cx}\mathrm{dx}-d\int\dfrac{1}{ax^2+bx+c}\mathrm{dx}=t+c$$

Solving the resulting integral (e.g. by partial fractions or looking them up in integral tables or using wolfram alpha) and then determining the explicit solution for $x(t)$ is complicated and will result in a very long expression. You can replace the $t$ with the variable that you were using.